# After changing anchor tag ID value, old click action is still bound to anchor

Tags: jquery, html

I have an anchor tag with id 'show' and a jquery script for id show. After the script runs it changes the id to 'hide'. When i click on the link again it still execute the jquery for id 'show'. Here's my code

```
$('#show').on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            data: {id: t},
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/get_logs/',
            success: function(result){
                $('#' + content_id).html(result)
                $('#' + show).attr('id',"hide")
            }
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Event bound to an element persists even after changing the part of the selector as the handler is defined/registered on DOM ready.

You need to unbind it explicitly.

Use `.unbind()` or `off()`

```
$('#'+show).off('click').attr('id','hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(document).on("click",'#show', function(){/*-- Code for show click*/});
$(document).on("click",'#hide', function(){/*-- Code for hide click*/});
```